# JavaScript: Problems in Snakes and Ladders Game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript. I am making Snakes and Ladders game. I am facing some problems on the code.

1. First I can not store the current position of the player so I can count the next destination.
2. The dice starts with 1 at the beginning of the game and this causes the player to start from the second cell.
3. The big snake and ladder divs displayed onto the board are not auto fit to the size of the board.

Here is the code I wrote so far [Snakes and Ladder Game](https://jsfiddle.net/safaasalem/6wz0knjo/2/)

```js
var gameBoard = {
  createBoard: function(dimension, mount) {
    var mount = document.querySelector(mount);
    if (!dimension || isNaN(dimension) || !parseInt(dimension, 10)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      dimension = typeof dimension === 'string' ? parseInt(dimension, 10) : dimension;
      var table = document.createElement('table'),
        row = document.createElement('tr'),
        cell = document.createElement('td'),
        rowClone,
        cellClone;
      var output;
      for (var r = 0; r < dimension; r++) {
        rowClone = row.cloneNode(true);
        table.appendChild(rowClone);
        for (var c = 0; c < dimension; c++) {
          cellClone = cell.cloneNode(true);
          rowClone.appendChild(cellClone);
        }
      }
      mount.appendChild(table);
      output = gameBoard.enumerateBoard(table);
    }
    return output;
  },
  enumerateBoard: function(board) {
    var rows = board.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
      text = document.createTextNode(''),
      rowCounter = 1,
      size = rows.length,
      cells,
      cellsLength,
      cellNumber,
      odd = false,
      control = 0;
    for (var r = size - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
      cells = rows[r].getElementsByTagName('td');
      cellsLength = cells.length;
      rows[r].className = r % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
      odd = ++control % 2 == 0 ? true : false;
      size = rows.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < cellsLength; i++) {
        if (odd == true) {
          cellNumber = --size + rowCounter - i;
        } else {
          cellNumber = rowCounter;
        }
        cells[i].className = i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
        cells[i].id = cellNumber;
        cells[i].appendChild(text.cloneNode());
        cells[i].firstChild.nodeValue = cellNumber;
        rowCounter++;
      }
    }
    var lastRow = rows[0].getElementsByTagName('td');
    lastRow[0].id = '100';
    var firstRow = rows[9].getElementsByTagName('td');
    firstRow[0].id = '1';
    return gameBoard;
  }
};
gameBoard.createBoard(10, "#grid");

function intialPosition() {
  $("#1").append($("#player1"));
  $("#1").append($("#player2"));
  var currentPosition = parseInt($("#1").attr('id'));
  return currentPosition;
}
var w = intialPosition();

var face1 = new Image()
face1.src = "http://s19.postimg.org/fa5etrfy7/image.gif"
var face2 = new Image()
face2.src = "http://s19.postimg.org/qb0jys873/image.gif"
var face3 = new Image()
face3.src = "http://s19.postimg.org/fpgoms1vj/image.gif"
var face4 = new Image()
face4.src = "http://s19.postimg.org/xgsb18ha7/image.gif"
var face5 = new Image()
face5.src = "http://s19.postimg.org/lsy96os5b/image.gif"
var face6 = new Image()
face6.src = "http://s19.postimg.org/4gxwl8ynz/image.gif"

function rollDice() {
  var randomdice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  document.images["mydice"].src = eval("face" + randomdice + ".src")
  if (randomdice == 6) {
    alert('Congratulations! You got 6! Roll the dice again');
  }
  return randomdice;
}
var random1 = rollDice();
var destination = w + random1;

function move() {
  $('#' + destination).append($("#player1"));
  var x = parseInt($('#' + destination).attr('id'));
  var random = rollDice();
  destination = x + random;
  //alert(x);
  return destination;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('#' + destination).delay(100).fadeOut().fadeIn('slow');
  $('#' + destination).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
});
var next = move();
```

```css
/*body {
    background-image: url('snakesandladder2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: #4f96cb;
}*/

#game {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: table;
}
#gameBoardSection {
  border: 3px inset #0FF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 65%;
  display: table-cell;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: PowderBlue;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even),
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: SkyBlue;
}
#100 {
  background-image: url('http://s19.postimg.org/ceioc1g8v/rotstar2_e0.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#ladder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 470px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#bigSnake {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 200px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 1;
}
#diceAndPlayerSection {
  background-color: lightpink;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  display: table-cell;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px inset #0FF;
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="gameBoardSection">
      <div id="grid"></div>
      <div id="ladder">
        <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/otai9he2n/oie_e_RDOY2iqd5o_Q.gif" />
      </div>
      <div id="bigSnake">
        <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/hrcknaagz/oie_485727s_RN4_KKBG.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="player1" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px;">
        <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/t108l496n/human_Piece.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="player2" style="position:absolute; top:15px; left:5px;">
        <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/l6zmzq1dr/computer_Piece.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="diceAndPlayerSection">
      <div id="reset">
        <button type="button" name="newGame" onClick="gameVM.newGame();">New Game</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" name="reset" onClick="gameVM.defaultSetup()">Reset</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" name="addPlayer">Add Player</button>
      </div>
      <div id="diceSection">
        <img src="d1.gif" name="mydice" onclick="rollDice()" style="background-color: white;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me on that? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're new to javascript, why would you start with something this complex?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a task  that I have to do.

Comment: Ah, so its school work? What does your course material say? What about your teacher? Im fairly certain Javascript 101 does not drop you straight onto a task this complex, there must have been bits leading up to this?

Comment: Also, every single one of your questions so far on SO have been you croudsourcing the code for this game, tell me - do we all get your course credits? Didnt think so!

Comment: My teacher did not asked us to code this game specifically, but he asked us to implement any game of our choice and I chose that game.

Comment: Bad choice - choose something MUCH simpler - tic tac toe, snap etc

Answer (score 1):

1. To store the user current position , maintain the separate variable for storing the destination of diff player.
2. To start the play from the 1 , remove intialPosition() and make var w=0 , so once you call the rolldice() , it will start from 0.
3. In order to auto fit based on the change in screen size , use the bootstrap div which can auto fit the size of the div. Here is the link for it http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid